# Get all columns of a table from a different database

Tags: sql-server, database

s there a syntax wherein I can get the columns of a table from a different database? I have tried using `select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Database_Name.DBO.Table_Name'` But it's not working. Please do help me, been doing this for days.

Comment: Query suggested in Eric's answer works fine only thing is you need to select the database for which you want the column names. It worked for me.

Comment: @PareshJ Yes, that's my problem now, how can I access the database of the table.

Comment: @PareshJ I am executing the above query using a different database,  for example, the columns that I want to get is from the table on another database? Is there a query for that? It's like this query -- USE ADHOC go select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Table_Name' and database_name = 'CONSO_GP'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're close.  TABLE_NAME has just the name of the table.  The rest of the information is in TABLE_CATALOG and TABLE_SCHEMA.  You can qualify information_schema with the catalog you want to select from:

```
select column_name from Database_Name.information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Table_Name' AND table_schema = 'dbo'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir but it's still not working, it loads no data when I execute it.

Comment: Does the user running that command have appropriate permissions?  Try just doing SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and see if you see what you expect.

Comment: Tried it, it loads all the tables and the columns of the database but, it doesn't load the tables and the columns of the database that I want to access.

Comment: Please keep in mind that I'm executing this query using a different database.

Comment: @eljon_i3: See my update.  You have to qualify information_schema with the catalog of interest.  You might still need table_schema (if you have schemas other than dbo) but you can drop table_catalog from the WHERE condition.

Comment: I am executing the above query using a different database,  for example, the columns that I want to get is from the table on another database? Is there a query for that? It's like this query -- USE ADHOC go select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Table_Name' and database_name = 'CONSO_GP'

Comment: My updated query does just that.  In my SSMS, with a query window connected to SchemaA, I was able to `select * from SchemaB.information_schema.columns` just fine, while just `select * from information_schema.columns` shows me the result for SchemaA.

Comment: Sir one last question, on the textbox I have 'DatabaseName.Dbo.TableName' how can I get the text "TableName" only? I have to use trim right? But how will I use that?

Comment: Stack overflow rule is to create a new question.  If you post a link to that question here, I am glad to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I found out. Each database has its own information_schema view so it won't show the information from the other databases. So if you want to get the column names for a table in another database, you have to use the information_schema view of that database.

{database name}.information_schema

Example:

```
SET @Sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @DBName, '.dbo.colname_table (column_name) 
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ', @DBName, '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''table_name'' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ''dbo'' 
    ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION');

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql;
```

where @DBName is the name of the database.

Answer (score 0):

The table names in the `information_schema.columns` system table do not have the `Database_Name.DBO.Table_Name` format. They just have the Table name as a varchar value. So try it like this:

```
USE Database_Name;
select column_name from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'Table_Name'
```

Comment: I can't use the 'USE Database_Name' because my syntax is in a stored procedure, and that stored procedure is from a different database, that's why I want to know how can I get the table from a different database.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
select column_name from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'Table_Name'
```

without this part

```
AND table_schema = 'dbo'
```